# Unable to pass packed array of handles to Win32::API call in Perl

Tags: perl, winapi, pack

I am trying to call Win32 API function from Perl using Win32::API, and pass it array of handles. The particular function is `WaitForMultipleObjects` and it doesn't like the way I feed parameters to it. Here's how it's defined in Perl:

```
 # DWORD WaitForMultipleObjects(DWORD nCount, HANDLE* handles, BOOL, DWORD)
 $WaitForMultipleObjects = new Win32::API::More('kernel32',
                                                'WaitForMultipleObjects', 'NPNN', 'N');
```

Then there's array of handles. All of them are confirmed valid and they all work when passed individually to `WaitForSingleObject`. 
Here's how I pack the parameters:

```
   my @handles; 
   ...
   my $n = scalar(@handles);
   my $handlePack = pack "L*", @handles; # also tried 'L1', 'L2', etc.
   $rc = $WaitForMultipleObjects->Call($n, $handlePack, 0, 0xffffffff); # fails
```

This fails and GetLastError() reports error 6 (The handle is invalid). 
However, if I pass only one handle, it works:

```
   my $handlePack = pack "L", $handles[0];
   $rc = $WaitForMultipleObjects->Call(1, $handlePack, 0, 0xffffffff); # works
```

Obviously Win32::API is not able to pass the array of handles correctly in the second parameter, but as far as I understand the documentation (https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::API), that's how it should be. Or is my usage of `pack()` wrong ? I am on 64-bit Perl, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is 64 bits. On 64-bit Windows (and in 64-bit Perl), sizeof(HANDLE) = 8 bytes. So if the program runs in 64-bit Perl, it loads 64-bit DLLs, and you have to pack handles using `Q` (i.e. 64-bit integers). Using `L` won't work because it packs 32-bit ints. The following fixes the problem:

```
use Config qw( %Config );

my $ptr_size = $Config{ptrsize};
my $ptr_format =
   $ptr_size == 4 ? "L" :
   $ptr_size == 8 ? "Q" :
   die("Unsupported pointer size $ptr_size\n");

my $handlePack = pack $ptr_format."*", @handles; 

$rc = $WaitForMultipleObjects->Call($n, $handlePack, 0, 0xffffffff);
```

Note that even in 64-bit Perl, `pack('I')` can still produce 32 bits (depending on the compiler). `pack('J')` (Perl's internal int) is also unsuitable because while it's at least as large as a pointer, it could be larger (e.g. a 32-bit Perl built using `-Duse64bitint`).